# How to run multiple postman collections in command or Newman

Tags: postman-collection-runner, postman-newman

I have few postman collections which i need to execute in single command.
I refer few suggestions but its not working.

```
Created a feed file.

newman run -f "D:\APIData\FeedFile.json"

{
    "runs":[
        {
            "collection": "D:\APIData\DE.postman_collection.json",
            "iterationData": "D:\APIData\APIAutomationData.csv"
        },
        {
            "collection": "D:\APIData\US.postman_collection.json",
            "iterationData": "D:\APIData\APIAutomationData.csv"
        },
        {
            "collection": "D:\APIData\IT.postman_collection.json",
            "iterationData": "D:\APIData\APIAutomationData.csv"
        }
    ]
}

But its not working. can someone help me.


Thanks
Nihar
```

Comment: create a batch file on add all connection and run